# When building a Handler, should it be .ashx or .axd?

Tags: asp.net

Say I'm building an ASP.Net class that inherits from `IHttpHandler`, should I wire this up to a URL ending in `.ashx`, or should I use the `.axd` extension?

Does it matter as long as there's no naming conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh.. ScottGu says it doesn't matter, but .ashx is slightly better because there's less chance of a conflict with things like trace.axd and others. That's why the flag went up in my head that .ashx might be better.

http://forums.asp.net/t/964074.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Out in "the wild", .ashx are definitely the most popular extension.