# Difference between axd and ashx handlers

Tags: asp.net

What is the Difference betweeen axd and ashx handlers.

Comment: Right there in the related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450/when-building-a-handler-should-it-be-ashx-or-axd

Answer (score 7):

The primary difference is **axd** handlers are used to download resources *embedded in an assembly*. so it is mostly used by control developers. On the other hand, **ashx** are generic handlers that process request. It is used mostly by asp.net developers.

The axd handler comes with asp.net 2.0.

See [this entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442) and [this](http://claytonj.wordpress.com/2006/11/05/aspnet-20-the-new-webresourceaxd-handler/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the ASP.NET uses .axd extension for Web Resources and uses`AssemblyResourceLoader`to handle it. But .ashx files that called Generic Handler is useful when you want to create an HttpHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, they're identical, they're both meant for HTTP handlers, i.e. code that implements IHttpHandler. But axd are implemented by ASP.NET itself and ashx are for you.

It is a convention, you could write an axd handler.